# Table input parameters and scalar output parameters

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, hana, python-db-api

I have the following table and the following stored procedure (simplified to the bare basics needed to demonstrate the problem):

```
CREATE TABLE T(C INT);
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC(IN T TABLE(C INT), OUT X INT) AS BEGIN
X = 5;
END;
```

From HANA Studio, I can `CALL PROC(T, ?)` and get 5. However, I have not found any good way to do the same from the [hdbcli Python driver](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/26/sap-hana-2.0-sps02-new-feature-updated-python-driver/).

`callproc` doesn't seem to have any way to accept table parameters. Passing the table name as a string doesn't work:

```
>>> from hdbcli import dbapi
>>> conn = dbapi.connect(userkey='testkey')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.callproc('PROC', ('T', '?'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hdbcli/dbapi.py", line 498, in callproc
    ret = self.__callproc(callproc, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hdbcli/dbapi.py", line 257, in __callproc
    return self.__cursor.callproc(operation, parameters)
hdbcli.dbapi.Error: (8, 'invalid argument: Input parameter is inadequate as table parameter: line 1 col 13 (at pos 12)')
```

`execute` can execute the procedure, but it doesn't seem to provide any way to access the output parameter. There's no result set for it:

```
>>> cur.execute('CALL PROC(T, ?)')
True
>>> cur.fetchone()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hdbcli/dbapi.py", line 434, in fetchone
    raise ProgrammingError(0,"No result set")
hdbcli.dbapi.ProgrammingError: (0, 'No result set')
```

I've found one extremely awkward workaround, which I'm posting as an answer, but it's horribly verbose and doesn't interact well with default parameter values. Is there a good way to access the output parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The one workaround I've found is to wrap the procedure in an anonymous block and stuff the scalar into a SELECT in the anonymous block:

```
>>> cur.execute('''
... DO BEGIN
... DECLARE X INT;
... T_VAR = SELECT * FROM T;
... CALL PROC(:T_VAR, X);
... SELECT :X FROM DUMMY;
... END''')
True
>>> cur.fetchone()
(5,)
```

That's a lot of extra typing. We can save a wrapper procedure to do this for us instead of repeating the anonymous block each time, but that can lead to a lot of wrapper procedures if you have a lot of procedures to wrap. Also, it doesn't play well with default values. If you have the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC2(OUT X INT, IN T TABLE(C INT) DEFAULT T) AS BEGIN
X = 5;
END;
```

You can normally call it as `CALL PROC2(?)`, but you can't call it from inside an anonymous block or stored procedure without passing an explicit value for `T`:

```
>>> cur.execute('''
... DO BEGIN
... DECLARE X INT;
... CALL PROC2(X);
... SELECT :X FROM DUMMY;
... END''')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hdbcli/dbapi.py", line 363, in execute
    ret = self.__execute(operation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hdbcli/dbapi.py", line 249, in __execute
    ret = self.__cursor.execute(operation, parameters=parameters, iscall=iscall, scrollable=self._scrollable)
hdbcli.dbapi.Error: (7, 'feature not supported: Only table variable is allowed in input parameter in a nested call: line 1 col 15 (at pos 14)')
```

That exception is happening due to the `T` default value.